# Extraneous argument label 'at:' in call

Tags: swift

Xcode report a argument label error when I define a method in my ViewController.

```
func badMethod() {
    let array = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0..<10 {
        array.insert(i, at: i)
    }

    for _ in 0...10 {
        array.remove(at: 0)  // <- Extraneous argument label 'at:' in call
    }
}
```

This error should not be report in early swift version, if there is a way to compatible with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an `NSMutableArray`, so the right method to call on that would be `array.removeObject(at: 0)`. Also, you're removing 11 elements but only add 10.

That said, this is Swift and you should use native arrays:

```
func betterMethod() {
    var array = [Int]()

    for i in 0..<10 {
        array.insert(i, at: i)
    }

    for _ in 0..<10 {
        array.remove(at: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try to at argument liket his

```
func badMethod() {
    let array = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0..<10 {
        array.insert(i, at: i)
    }

    for _ in 0...10 {
        array.remove(0)  // <- Extraneous argument label 'at:' in call
    }
}
```

Comment: yes , argument label removed inn your current version of swift . try this its working .

Comment: @EkramulHoque: OP wants to remove the array element at *index zero* (i.e. the first array element). Your suggested code removes all array elements which are *equal to zero.*